# setState then recursively function call in React JS

Tags: reactjs

On button click, i am checking availability of all servers one by one. Once first server check is done then it will recursively call same function with ++index. The code is as below:

```
tempA = (index) => {
    console.log("index is--> " + index);
    let oRecord = this.state.aServers[index];
    let componentStatus = {};
    componentStatus[oRecord.id] = <div className='icon--loading'> 
</div>

    this.setState({
        componentStatus: componentStatus
    });
    var request = "component? 
operation=check_server_pingability&target_server=" + oRecord.name + 
"&_=" + getDateTime();

    fetch(request, {
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            componentStatus[oRecord.id] = <div title= 
{response.message} className={"icon icon--" + response.status + " 
cell"}></div>
            this.setState({
                componentStatus: componentStatus
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.componentStatus[oRecord.id])
                this.tempA(++index);
            });
        })
   }
```

First it will set icon as loading icon. Then after network call it should update icon as fail or success. After first server check is done it should perform same steps with next server in list. Now problem is, once first server check is done it updated the icon as failed but when it start checking second server the first server status got vanished and showing blank. It's happening with all the servers present in the list. Whenever it go to check next server the earlier servers status are getting vanished. Please check the code and let me know where the problem is. Thanks for help.

Comment: if fetch() is always returning a response, there is no terminate condition for the recursion.

Comment: Yeah terminate condition is missing. I'll handle that later.

Comment: In that case, you will surely get 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. It might be the reason you are not getting the consistent result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in line 
`let componentStatus = {};` each time you put in state object `componentStatus` which has only one field(`[oRecord.id]`). You should try to change this line on this one:

`let componentStatus = this.state.componentStatus;`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. It cleared my understanding as well.

Comment: it should be `let componentStatus = { ...this.state.componentStatus };`